# Fill data from userform to next row

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a userform, but I can't manage to fill the data from it to the next row every time, it always fills the same row.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub btnivesti_Click()
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet

    Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lapas1")

    ssheet.Cells(3) = CDate(Me.tddate)
    ssheet.Cells(1) = Me.cmblistitem
    ssheet.Cells(4) = Me.tbpo
    ssheet.Cells(6) = Me.tbkodas
    ssheet.Cells(8) = Me.tbkiekis

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.tddate = Date

    'fill drop box

    For Each cell In [listas1]
        Me.cmblistitem.AddItem cell
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: could you improve your question- it is not clear what you are asking about?

Comment: Since the cells defined in your topmost macros are always the same (3, 1, 4, etc.) it is no wonder that the macro doesn't move between rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code references the cell number. Cell number determines cell location by counting the number of cells individually (Row 1 would have cell numbers from 1 to 16384, Row 2 from 16385 to 32768, etc.), which is highly inefficient. Instead, you should reference the row and column where you want to put your data.

Since you want to fill new data to new rows, get the location of the last row with data on it and increment by 1. Try this:

```
Private Sub btnivesti_Click()
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow as Integer

    Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lapas1")
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ssheet.Cells(lastrow, 3) = CDate(Me.tddate)
    ssheet.Cells(lastrow, 1) = Me.cmblistitem
    ssheet.Cells(lastrow, 4) = Me.tbpo
    ssheet.Cells(lastrow, 6) = Me.tbkodas
    ssheet.Cells(lastrow, 8) = Me.tbkiekis

End Sub
```

Comment: One more small question, tbkiekis should not be imputed as text, but as a digit, how should I change the code to do that? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could use the `isNumeric` function to check if `tbkiekis` is a number. Then add a condition that if it returns true, the data will be filled.

Comment: Do you mean like: if tbkiekis.isnumeric, then

Comment: `If isNumeric(Me.tbkiekis) Then 'FillData`